# How to save data in array in order to print it sorted in O(n) time?

Tags: data-structures

In a game, a user can add `1` in each turn to one counter from `n` counters (numbered `1,2,...,n`). For this game he have:

- A function `counter(i)` that returns the content of counter `i`. in `O(1)` time.
- A function `add(i)` that increases the `i` counter. in `O(1)` time.
- A function `print()` that prints the id's sorted by the counter content, in descending order. in `O(n)` time.

How to implement such game in `O(n)`  place?

I know I should keep the counters in array but how can I print them sorted in `O(n)` time?

Comment: Is the requiremen to print sorted by the count or sorted by the id?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen print the id sorted by the counter's content

Comment: Your third stipulation uses the phrase "the id's" despite the fact that this has no antecedent nor natural reference. What "id's" are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnColeman let's say the counters are numbered `1,2,...,n`

Comment: Is this coursework? I am asking to see if we know that this can actually be done.

Comment: @Thilo yes, and can be done using arrays and linked lists.

Comment: I was thinking of keeping a linked list, too, but how to update that in O(1)? Any restrictions on how high the counters can go?

Comment: @Thilo No, there isn't. Maybe a list of counters content? such that a node of `3` point to all counter that have `3` in them? something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it with an array and linked-list of linked lists.

The array is mapping from counter id to the counter object I'll later describe.

The main list is a list that each node represents counter amount. Each such node has a list of all the counter-objects that has that amount, each one has a pointer back to the main list's node (the node who represents the amount).

When you are increasing counter `i`, you can get your object with your array in `O(1)` time, than you can use the pointer you have to reach the node that this object resides in, and to see what is the amount it represents. Now you can simply detach the counter object, and attach it to the next list in `O(1)` time (and create such a list if it doesn't exist).

The print is simple and will take `O(n)` just by traversing the main list.

[image: Draw]